# In the low volume review queues, passing an audit should ensure I get a real review to do

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits

This just happened to me again. I pass an audit, click next, and `there are no more items for you to review`. Not fair!

Today it happened that I did one real one, passed an audit, and then there was nothing. In the past I have had only an audit and never a real one for my troubles.

I believe we did something with edit reviews where other people couldn't do them while you were doing them. Can we do the same for everything except edit and close queues, where you get me a review to do, keep others from getting it, then show me an audit? If I fail, maybe you can even release my hold on it as a hand slap but if I pass, I would get the real review to do. Feels fairer to me.

Comment: I think it's even worse than that.  Yesterday I failed an audit on Programmers, and it capped me at 20 close reviews (when previously, I'm pretty sure I had 40).

Comment: I get this all the time, very frustrating.

Comment: No idea what my cap is outside of close since it's a rare day when I get more than 4 or 5 reviews to do.

Comment: At the 5 minute mark, hit F5 a dozen times, get no review tasks, look for 5 minutes how the avatars flip to the right, repeat until boredom strikes....